# calling a FA2 smart contract transfer entrypoint from my contract in smartpy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, transfer, fa2

Hello guys I am trying to call from my contract entry point from FA2 token contract that I have deployed. But I am unable to find anything on the internet.

The only thing I found from the documentation is this

```
c1.transfer([
    sp.record(
        from_ = alice.address,
        txs = [ sp.record(to=bob.address, amount=10, token_id=0),
                sp.record(to=bob.address, amount=10, token_id=1)]),
    sp.record(
        from_ = bob.address,
        txs = [sp.record(to_=alice.address, amount=11, token_id=0)])]
).run(sender = charlie)
```

But I can’t find a way on how I can implement it from my entry point here

```
@sp.entry_point
def exchange_tez(self):
    # Sanity checks
    sp.verify(sp.amount >= sp.tez(1), "INVALID AMOUNT")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by understanding how to call one contract from another. You can refer to this resource for more details: [Call one contract from another](https://forum.smartpy.io/t/call-one-contract-from-another/34).

In SmartPy, you have the ability to call a method in another contract by using `sp.transfer`.

`c1.transfer` is restrained to test scenario.

Here's the syntax for `sp.transfer`:

[`sp.transfer(argument: t, amount: sp.mutez, destination: sp.contract[t])`](https://smartpy.io/manual/syntax/operations#sp.transfer):

- `argument` is the same argument as `c1.transfer`
- `amount` is an amount of tez (most of the time `sp.tez(0)`)
- `destination` is the destination contract, obtained by calling `sp.contract(t, address: sp.address, entrypoint="transfer")` and `.unwrap_some()`.

Below is an example where I use these concepts. Note that I use `t.transfer_params` from the `fa2_lib`, but you can specify the full type directly:

```
list[sp.record(
    from_=sp.address,
    txs=list[sp.record(
            to_=sp.address,
            token_id=sp.nat,
            amount=sp.nat,
        ).layout(("to_", ("token_id", "amount")))],
).layout(("from_", "txs"))]
```

Here is a full example:

```
import smartpy as sp
from templates import fa2_lib

# Accessing transfer_params from fa2_lib
t, main = fa2_lib.t, fa2_lib.main

@sp.module
def m():
    class MyContract(sp.Contract):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        @sp.entrypoint
        def call_transfer(self, fa2_address, args):
            # Get contract from the address
            fa2_contract = sp.contract(t.transfer_params, fa2_address, entrypoint="transfer")
            # Call the transfer entrypoint in the FA2 contract
            sp.transfer(args, sp.tez(0), fa2_contract.unwrap_some(error="Contract not found"))

if "templates" not in __name__:
    @sp.add_test(name="MyContract")
    def test():
        sc = sp.test_scenario([t, main, m])
        c1 = m.MyContract()
        sc += c1
        fa2 = main.Fungible(sp.big_map(), {}, [])
        sc += fa2
        # Here we give the args
        # They can also be created inside the entrypoint.
        c1.call_transfer(sp.record(
            fa2_address=fa2.address,
            args=[]))
```